# Update Parent domain Cookie value from Sub-domain using javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, subdomain

I have Two domain like

1. example.com (parent domain)
2. example2.com (sub domain)

Now I am in my sub domain application and i can change any cookie here using javascript in client side.Now i want to that cookie with that same name in my parent domain application(if the cookie exits value will be updated).

How can i achieve this using javascript.

What i have tried ......

```js
 function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue) {
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" +encodeURIComponent("0#"+cookieValue) + "; path=/";
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" +encodeURIComponent("0#"+cookieValue) + ";domain=example2.com";
    }
```

In the above code first one is working for own domain but second line that can't change the parent domain value.

Any Idea?Thanks

Comment: Try using `localStorage` instead of cookies. It might work.

Comment: @Devashish Thanks for your suggestion.But my full application is managed by cookie.I have to try to manage using cookie first.if it is totally impossible then i will think any other way.